# adding custom pagination and filter in vue version 2.6

Tags: vuejs2

From Vue docs [Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-for-Range-Values-changed)  ,Its says that Vue 2 is not supporting limitBy,filterBy in v-for tag. I have to create a list view with custom pagination and search. I don't want the use the table search my UI looks like

[image: search vue]

The search function works fine here. I want to add pagination to this vue. This is my code

```
     <ul class="project_names mt-xl-5 mt-3">

        <li v-for="item in filteredList">

            <a :href="'/InvoicePages/Projects/Create?id='+item.Id" class="edit">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="../../wwwroot/lib/tuna/images/project_ico.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h4>{{item.Name}}</h4>

                        <h6 style="display: inline-block;width: 110px;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;">Total amount</h6>
                        <span style="color: #000;">: $ {{item.SubmittedAmount}}</span>

                        <h6 style="display: inline-block;width: 110px;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;">current budget revision</h6>
                        <span style="color: #000;">: {{item.BudgetRevisionNo}}</span>

                        <h6 style="display: inline-block;width: 110px;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;">unallocated</h6>
                        <span style="color: #000;">: $ {{item.SubmittedAmount}}</span>

                        <h6 style="display: inline-block;width: 110px;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;">PO's</h6>
                        <span style="color: #000;">: $ {{item.UnallocattedAmount}}</span>

                        <h6 style="display: inline-block;width: 110px;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;">invoiced</h6>
                        <span style="color: #000;">: $ {{item.UnallocattedAmount}}</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>


 
    </ul>
```

and script is

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "project-list",
    data: () => ({
        Project: ProjectJson,
        search: '',
   
    }),
    computed: {
        filteredList() {
        this.Project.filter(project => {
                return project.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) 
                    || project.BudgetRevisionNo.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                    || project.UnallocattedAmount.toString().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                    || project.SubmittedAmount.toString().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())

        })
      
        },
   
    }
};
```

My question is how can I add pagination to this vue and the computed function filteredList() to return results based on pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are few steps to follow. let me try if i could expalin clearly

firstly you need pagination component. you can implement it yourself but there are
already good components available. lets take [this one](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-sliding-pagination-vue-component/)
follow installation and confugation procedure and create appropiate methods.

The component will emit an event with page no for each page select. So now you know which page to show.

lets assume you have total 25 documents and you want to show 5 documents per page. so total there will be 5 pages.

Now if the user select say page 3 you have to query and get documents from 11 to 15
likewise if user select page 5 you have to query and get documents from 21-25

Now normally you would do a paginated query to db but in your caes I assume you have a list of your projects
in an array. (if not somehow convert it to an array and sort it based on any filed for consistency).
So you have an array of projects and for each user page select just calculate the start and end index
and may be save it to another array (for simplicity) over which you would loop throug and make your project card.